# how to use 'find ' query for geojson database

Tags: mongodb, geojson

i used my query to find a collection by giving x y coordinates. but no result was fetched. i have add a image of my database. i required to return just only the properties document which is corresponds to that coordinate.
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc5QE.png)

```
  db.getCollection('line').find(
  {"features" :
    [ 
    {
        "properties" : {
       ,
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                79.8658999999999960, 
                6.8513479999999998
    ]
    }
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
db.getCollection('user').find(
{"features" :

  {
    "properties" : {

           "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            79.8658999999999960, 
            6.8513479999999998]}}}})
```

Comment: no . Its not working. i have add an image of database. i just need to get properties document which is corresponds to that coordinate.